# PyQt4 QtCore.so symbol not found error

Tags: python, macos, pyqt4

I installed sip and PyQt but when i execute a python code like `python tutorial.py` , take this error. I installed pyqt with brew install and configure.py both.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 4, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN10QArrayData11shared_nullE
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this problem with delete Python and installing python and pyqt with macPorts.